# default behavior if command line argument not provided

Tags: java

I have written a java code to create a file if file name is provided in command line argument, if command line argument is not entered it will create file in default folder

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Outputlogs {


    private final String path = "C:/temp/logs.txt";


    public void createLogFile(String fileName) 
    {
        if(fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty())
        {

            File yourFile = new File(fileName);
            if(!yourFile.exists()) {
                try {
                    yourFile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
            } 

        else
        {
            File yourFile = new File(path);
            if(!yourFile.exists()) {
                try {
                    yourFile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
}

}
public class MainClass()
{
public static void main(String[] argv)
{

  String fileName = argv[0];

Outputlogs logs= new Outputlogs();
logs.createLogFile(fileName);
}
```

If i am providing command line arguments, its successfully creating the file but if command line argument is not entered, i am getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
How to achieve my scenario if command line argument is not entered it should create default folder. Please help

Comment: Please post your `main` method.

Comment: check the length of command line argument, if it is `0` then use default

Comment: What line is throwing the out-of-bounds exception?

Comment: It sounds like you are accessing an element in the argument array that doesn't exist. We need to see your main() method.

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with the error as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       if (args.length > 0)
          createLogFile(args[0]) ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    private static final String path = "C:/temp/logs.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length > 0) {
           createLogFile(args[0]);
        } else {
           createLogFile(path);
        }
    }

    public static void createLogFile(String fileName) 
    {
        File f = new File(fileName);
        if(!f.exists()) {
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that at some point, you are setting filename = args[0], otherwise you wouldn't be getting an array access error. If no argument is provided, the array args will be null, so accessing args[0] will return an ArrayIndexOutofBounds exception. Just check the length first:

```
if(args.length > 0)
    fileName = args[0];
else
    fileName = path;
```

Then you can combine your if/else statement into a single statement since at this point it filename will be either the argument or your default path:

```
 File yourFile = new File(fileName);
    if(!yourFile.exists()) {
        try {
            yourFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: At least, this is the only answer I can think of with the code you posted. If the error is coming from outside this code, we will need more information

Comment: Thanks for all your replies

Comment: If `args` was null you would get a NullPointerException — to be precise, args is a non-null String array with length==0 and arrays use zero-based indices, so `args[0]` refers to the first array element but there is no first element in a zero-length array.

Comment: Very true. I don't understand where the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception is coming from, then. Still, the code should work and fix the problem he specifically asked about.

Answer (score 0):

argv[0] means the first element in the argument-list (Array), so you have to check if there is at least one argument provided.
You can check the amount of items in the array with array.length, so everything above 0 will tell you that you can access the first (or second,third) argument.

```
public static void main(String[] argv)
{

  String fileName = (argv.length > 0) ? argv[0]:path; // changed

Outputlogs logs= new Outputlogs();
logs.createLogFile(fileName);
}
```

This line will check if the length of the array is above 0 set the fileName to argv[0] if it is or take the path variable if it isn't.